# How to use PETSc to calculate the first k eigenpair of symmetric Compressed Sparse Row Matrix?

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigenvalue, eigenvector, petsc

I need to decompose the eigenvalues of the large-scale(such as 10M*10M) sparse matrix as quickly as possible.I try Spectra but it is slow,It seems that Blaze cannot be used for the first k eigenpair computation of sparse matrix(It can calculate eigenvalues from dense matrix using eigen().So now I want to try PETSc.I find MatCreateSeqAIJCUSPARSE and MatSetValues to initialize sparse matrix,but I didn't find sparse matrix eigensolver.Does anyone know which function should I use and how to use it?It's better to give examples.

Answer (score 0):

You need the Slepc library which builds eigensolvers on top of Petsc. It can be installed by the petsc installer, but has its own documentation.
https://slepc.upv.es/documentation/